# Install ubuntu on my KVM VM by proxmox

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, proxmox, operating-system

I'm a newbie here but I would like to understand how to install ubuntu or centOS on my VM created by KVM (in proxmox). During creation, I've set

```
Linux 3.X/2.6 Kernel (l26)
```

in sheet OS and

```
Do not use any media
```

in CD/DVD sheet.
Now, in proxmox console for this VM, there is : "No bootable device". 
This is normal but how to install one without having acces to USB or CD/DVD reader...

Make an iso image of a specific distribution ?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know you can put ISO image here

`/var/lib/vz/template/iso`

Then you can install guest OS from web interface.

Answer (score 0):

I did not work with Promox but according to a common VM deployment process: just download distribution iso image you like and attach it as a virtual CD/DVD during VM deployment.